# How to grep for all-but-one matching columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to subset a large data frame with my columns of interest.  I do so using the grep function, this selects one column too many ("has_socio"), which I would like to remove.

The following code does exactly what I want, but I find it unpleasant to look at.  I want to do it in one line.  Aside from just calling the first subset inside the second subset, can it be optimized?

```
DF <- read.dta("./big.dta")

DF0 <- na.omit(subset(DF, select=c(other_named_vars, grep("has_",names(DF)))))
DF0 <- na.omit(subset(DF0, select=-c(has_socio)))
```

I know similar questions have been asked (e.g. [Subsetting a dataframe in R by multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244217/subsetting-a-dataframe-in-r-by-multiple-conditions?rq=1)) but I do not find one that addresses this issue specifically.  I recognize I could just write the grep RE more carefully, but I feel the above code more clearly expresses my intent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your grep with:

```
vec <- c("blah", "has_bacon", "has_ham", "has_socio")
grep("^has_(?!socio$)", vec, value=T, perl=T)
# [1] "has_bacon" "has_ham"
```

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead operator, which looks ahead and makes sure that its contents do not follow the actual matching piece behind of it (`has_` being the matching piece).

Comment: It seems the correct way is indeed to make my RE more specific.  I used standard (not perl) RE syntax, which is a bit shorter: `grep("has_[^s]")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
setdiff(grep("has_", vec, value = TRUE), "has_socio")
## [1] "has_bacon" "has_ham"
```