# R subset with condition using %in% or ==. Which one should be used?

Tags: r, subset

Usually, if I want to subset a dataframe conditioning of some values a variable I'm using subset and %in%:

```
x <- data.frame(u=1:10,v=LETTERS[1:10])
x
subset(x, v %in% c("A","D"))
```

Now, I found out that also == gives the same result:

```
subset(x, v == c("A","D"))
```

I'm just wondering if they are identically or if there is a reason to prefere one over the other.
Thanks for help.

Edit (@MrFlick): This question asks not the same as [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244217/subsetting-a-dataframe-in-r-by-multiple-conditions) which asks how to not include several values: `(!x %in% c('a','b'))`. I asked why I got the same if I use `==`or `%in%`.

Comment: you want `%in%`, `==` only works here because of a lucky coincidence between recycling rules and the length of both vectors. Consider `1:10 == c(1,3)` to convince yourself that it's a coincidence.

Comment: You almost exclusively could use `%in%` (and `==` for special occasions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the first one `%in%` because you got the result only because in the example dataset, it was in the order of recycling of `A`, `D`. Here, it is comparing

```
rep(c("A", "D"), length.out= nrow(x))
# 1] "A" "D" "A" "D" "A" "D" "A" "D" "A" "D"

 x$v==rep(c("A", "D"), length.out= nrow(x))# only because of coincidence
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE


subset(x, v == c("D","A"))
#[1] u v
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

while in the above

```
 x$v==rep(c("D", "A"), length.out= nrow(x))
 #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

whereas `%in%` works

```
subset(x, v %in% c("D","A"))
#  u v
#1 1 A
#4 4 D
```