# Reverse filter/subset dataframe

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have data that looks something like:

```
print(dat)
i1  i2  node_id
 4   4        8
 4   5        8
 3   2        9
 5   1        8
```

Using either dplyr's `filter` or `subset`(preferably filter)  I would like to reverse filter the data so I get this:

```
 print(dat)
 i1  i2  node_id
 4   4        8
 4   5        8
 5   1        8
```

I say reverse filter because instead of filtering or sub-setting like:

```
dat<-filter(dat,node_id==8)
dat<-subset(dat,node_id==8)
```

I would like to do this by telling R I want to keep everything except where the node_id==9
I have tried:

```
dat<-filter(dat,-node_id==9)
dat<-subset(dat,-node_id==9)
```

But neither work.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: try `filter(dat, node_id != 9)`

Comment: Ah yes perfect thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reverse filtering for `<, >, <=, >=`

I know it's not specifically asked, but in case of reverse filtering for cases `<, >, <=, >=` conditions, if you wanted all the `node_id < 9`following would work

`dat <- dat %>% filter(!node_id >= 9)`

which is same as

`dat <- dat %>% filter(node_id < 9)`

Comment: Thank you very much I will use this.

Answer (score 2):

### `subset()` with multiple conditions

This is not directly relevant to OP, but could help someone else with situations where you have `subset()` with multiple conditions.

Say you have a data frame `dat` and you have a subset of `dat` named `A.df`. You want to get `B.df` which excludes `A.df` from `dat`.

[One approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244267/9645167) is using `!` to reverse the combination of conditions:

```
A.df <- subset(dat, Col1 %in% criteria | Col2 %in% criteria | Col3 %in% criteria)
```

becomes

```
B.df <- subset(dat, !(Col1 %in% criteria | Col2 %in% criteria | Col3 %in% criteria))
```

But this might not be suitable in nested subset (i.e. subset of a subset and so on).

Another approach is using `rownames()` to exclude certain rows. This approach works for subset with multiple conditions and nested subset.

Say dat has rows of `1,2,3,4,5` while A.df has rows of `3,4`. So, we exclude those rows to get `1,2,5` for B.df.

```
dat$ID <- rownames(dat)
B.df <- subset(dat, !(ID %in% rownames(A.df)))
```

First line is to take the names of every row of `dat` (by default is `1,2,3,...`) and append them to a new column.